# Add Object to NSMutableArray even it is check marked

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I try to add the `cell.textlabel.text` to an NSMutableArray even it is check marked. I do this with following code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    else{
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        self.selectedDays = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self.selectedDays addObject:cell.textLabel.text];

        NSLog(@"%@", self.selectedDays);

    }
}
```

But it does not add, but replace.

```
    2015-06-28 xx:xx:xx xxxx - xxxx[xxx:xxx] (
    Monday
    )
    2015-06-28 xx:xx:xx xxxx - xxxx[xxx:xxx] (
    Tuesday
    )
    2015-06-28 xx:xx:xx xxxx - xxxx[xxx:xxx] (
    Wednesday
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time a cell is tapped you're doing

```
self.selectedDays = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Which is throwing away the old array and creating a new one. Then you add one thing to it.

Move that line of code to `viewDidLoad` Instead so you just create th array once.

You should really use your data model instead of getting the text from the cell though...

Comment: Thanks, that was my problem